# Alfresco 4.0 Community and Solr are producing too many queries on Mysql 5.1

Tags: mysql, performance, solr, alfresco

i'm having big performance issues with Alfresco 4.0 (using Solr) and Mysql 5.1

checking with mysqlreport i've found that the problem seems caused by solr.

on a normal start, alfresco generates 578.89k SELECT and counting, in 10 minutes, without any connection whatsoever

disabling solr by commenting the part in alfresco-global.properties (and getting some exceptions) the SELECT count stops at 239

Using index.recovery.mode=NONE did not help at all, as well as setting the indexing flags to false in cm:content a false in /tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/model/contentModel.xml

switching to Lucene, though it lowers the count, causes other problems in the web application, so i can't use it as a viable solution.

i'm still reading the manual in order to come up with a solution, but i'm quite lost.

Does anyone have some suggestion?

Thanks for your time and help

Enrico

Comment: disabling solr like that wont work.
read here: http://deepak-keswani.blogspot.ch/2012/12/how-to-disable-solr-enable-lucene-on.html

Comment: Thanks, i used that solution when i tested lucene. As i wrote, even if  it lowered a bit the number of queries over 10 minutes, Lucene doesn't return the same results when searching Alfresco with CMIS

Comment: when you enabled lucene, which properties did you use? did the log tell you that the index was rebuild?

Comment: Yes, it did. As for lucene properties, i followed the link's instruction. First FULL, then AUTO.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with the CMIS bootstrap subsystem. To get the best performance out of the startup, you should a) try [upgrading](http://docs.alfresco.com/community/concepts/ch-upgrade.html) to the latest [Alfresco Version](http://www.alfresco.com/products/community/download), where this issue may have been fixed. b) Verify that the latency between your DBMS and the Alfresco Repository is as little as you can get it, and that your [environment is optimally provisioned](https://code.google.com/p/alfresco-environment-validation/) c) Use the [supported MySQL Connector](http://www.alfresco.com/services/subscription/supported-platforms) as your DBMS driver.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried the validator and corrected a couple of things, but with no result. Now i'm trying to upgrade to Alfresco 5.0